# How to use PHP to sum SQL data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum, addition

I want to have a "toplist" type thing for my forum. I have a kill log for a pc game. So in my sql table 'victims' i have couple of rows for data. I want to take to use $killforumid to sum $score for the entire table. there are multiple entries with the same $killforumid, and i want to sort with that and add up the score for that user.

It would look like this:

```
User 1 = 1000 points, 60 kills
User 2 = 5000 points, 100 kills
```

PHP code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT score, killforumid FROM hcvictims";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: you could do most if not all the calculations inside the query

Comment: you want to use aggregate functions.  so `SELECT sum(score), killforumid FROM hcvictims GROUP BY killforumid ORDER BY sum(score) DESC`

Comment: Right... but how do i echo them with killforumid - score

Answer (score 0):

if you're using [RightClick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3621140/rightclick) query (as i'll advise):

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT sum(score), killforumid FROM hcvictims GROUP BY killforumid ORDER BY sum(score) DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
while($row = $result->fetch_row())
{
    echo "killforumid: " . $row[1] . ", score : " . $row[0] . "\n"; 
}
/* free result set */
$result->free();
```

see: [mysqli-result object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), 
     [fetch-row method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)